# Adding "List of Equations" into an existing latex style sty file

Tags: equations

was provided with the standard *.sty file and the main.tex.

The standard sty file does not contain page for "List of Equations." By following the guide from [url][https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=428[/url]](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=428%5B/url%5D) I managed to generate the page by adding the following code into the *.sty file.

```
\renewcommand{\listequationsname}{\normalsize\normalfont\centering\vspace*{-0.5in} LIST OF EQUATIONS}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LIST OF EQUATIONS} 
\listofmyequations
\fi
```

In the main.tex file and chapters, I have each equation tagged with \myequations label.

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{D\rho}{Dt}+\rho(\bigtriangledown \cdot \overrightarrow{\rm V}) = 0
\label{eqn:conversation of mass}
\end{equation}
\myequations{conversation of mass}

Where $\rho$ is density, $V$ is velocity and, $\bigtriangledown$ is gradient operator.

\begin{equation}
\rho \frac{DV}{Dt} = -\bigtriangledown P + \rho g + \mu \bigtriangledown^{2}V
\label{eqn:conservation of momentum}
\end{equation}
\myequations{conservation of momentum}
```

The List of Equation page was generated successfully and also appear in the Table of Content. But there are 2 problems. I would like to ask the following:

1. How do I add the word Equation to each of the equation on the "List of Equations" page.
2. Why the page number is the same for List of Figures and List of Equations? My List of Equation page come after List of Figures.

Comment: Off-topic: Please write `\overrightarrow{\mathrm{V}}`, not `\overrightarrow{\rm V}`, `\rm` is plain-TeX notation that's no longer defined in the LaTeX kernel and is not defined by some of the widely used LaTeX document classes. That said, why do you wish to render the letter `V` in the upright font shape? Later on in your code snippet, one finds `$V$ is velocity`, which uses the italic font shape.

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution is to create a new float type and use `\caption`, but there is a limit on how much you can borrow without conflicting with the other definition of `\equation`, `\equation*`, `\c@equation` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=loe,listname={List of Equations}]{eqn}
\newcommand{\eqnlabel}[1]{\addcontentsline{loe}{eqn}{\string\numberline{\theequation}#1}}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document} 

\listofeqns

\begin{equation}
x=a
\eqnlabel{For list of equations}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

After 12 hours trying, I figured out the problem:

```
%%%%%   List of Equations
               \iffigurespage
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{\normalsize\normalfont\centering\vspace*{-0.5in} LIST OF EQUATIONS}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{Equation \protect\numberline{\theequation} #1}\par}
        \clearpage %this is to add new page
        \phantomsection %this is to add new page, without these command, the page will be the same as the previous
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LIST OF EQUATIONS}
\listofmyequations
\fi
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: BTW, there is a  revised solution which can handle \tag at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583430/how-to-get-the-tag