# How to get the \tag

Tags: amsmath

I was working on yet another `\listofequations` solution ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583419/adding-list-of-equations-into-an-existing-latex-style-sty-file/583426#583426)), when I noticed that neither `\theequation` nor `\@currentlabel` work with `\tag`.  Other LOE solutions don't seem to address the problem, and I can't find anything useful in amsmath.sty.  (Just lots of things that don't work.)

I could use a `\mytag` macro, but that would be a last resort.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=loe,listname={List of Equations}]{eqn}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\eqnlabel}[1]{\addcontentsline{loe}{eqn}{\string\numberline{\@currentlabel}#1}}
\newcommand{\mytag}[1]{\tag{#1}\edef\@currentlabel{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 

\listofeqns

\begin{equation}
x=a
\eqnlabel{For list of equations}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y=b \tag{A} \label{test}
\eqnlabel{tag test}
\end{equation}

\ref{test}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Strange, because `\tag` sets `\@currentlabel` (haven't digged too deep, though).

Comment: +1: Maybe a MWE would attract more experts?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - Sorry about the delay.  I've been freezing in the dark for two days.

Comment: Omg, are you based in the US?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - Houston, Texas.  I am still getting rolling blackouts.

Comment: Ok, crazy. I recently moved to California (from Germany, China).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is a scope issue.

If I am reading `amsmath.sty` right: the redefinition of `\@currentlabel` only happens when printing the tag. To do so `\tag` sets `\df@tag` to a command that prints the tag and sets the `\@currentlabel`. And the way `\label` works in `amsmath.sty` is a bit complicated. The `\label` command is redefined to store the label in `\df@label`, and *when* the equation number is generated, it checks to see if `\df@label` is defined and if so it calls the original LaTeX `\label`.

The key thing here is that the setting of `\@currentlabel` is very severely scoped. And if you try to access `\@currentlabel` away from when the tag is generated, you will fail to actually pick up the correct value.

So this also suggests a solution: `amsmath.sty` stores the tag values in `\df@tag`.
When you call it, it generates both the printed form of the tag using `\maketag@@@` and sets the `\@currentlabel`. So you can locally set the `\@currentlabel` by calling `\df@tag` yourself, after swapping out `\maketag@@@` so you don't print another copy of the equation label.

Proof of concept (there may be unintended side effects):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=loe,listname={List of Equations}]{eqn}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\eqnlabel[1]{%
        \ifmeasuring@
        \else
        \begingroup
                \let\maketag@@@\@gobble
                \df@tag
                \addcontentsline{loe}{eqn}{\string\numberline{\@currentlabel}{#1}}
        \endgroup
        \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\listofeqns

\begin{equation}
x=a
\eqnlabel{For list of equations}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
        y=b \tag{A} \label{test}
\eqnlabel{tag test}
\end{equation}

\ref{test}

\end{document}
```

The generated `.aux` file shows now correctly

```
\relax 
\@writefile{loe}{\contentsline {eqn}{\numberline{1}{For list of equations}}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{loe}{\contentsline {eqn}{\numberline{{A}}{tag test}}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{test}{{{A}}{1}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Comment: I don’t think you need `\old@currentlabel`

Comment: @egreg: Yeah.. that was silly. What I get for answering a question at 2:30 in the morning.

Comment: I stopped thinking to it at  about 1am