# Labeling Equations in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, equations, amsmath

I am working with a class file that creates a new TOC for a new list as follows:

```
    \chapter*{\listname\ #1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{\listname\ #1}}{\listname\ #1}}}
    \begingroup
}{\par\endgroup}
```

It is showing up as 'EQUATIONS' in the overall TOC and even has its own page, but now I need to label my equations so that they show up in the EQUATION TOC (like list of figures). I've tried to combine the formatting of the \newenvironment in the class file with amsmath call \theeuqation   using the following:

```
\newenvironment{listequation}[1]{%
    \chapter*{\listname\ #1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{\theequation\ #1}}{\theequation\ #1}}}
    \begingroup
}{\par\endgroup}
```

But when I add the following, nothing shows up in my Equations TOC:

```
\begin{equation}
AGC = Q_{fr} * \alpha_ {f} 
\end{equation}
\label{Equation 1}
\label{\theequation}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: You have two consecutive `\label` commands. I use this, which I probably found on here somewhere: `\newcommand{\eqlabel}[2]{\label{#1}\addcontentsline{equ}{equations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#2}}` and then use `\begin{equation}\eqlabel{AGC}{Equation for AGC}AGC=Q\end{equation}` Needs `\listofequations` on your contents page

Comment: You might be better of [with this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583430/how-to-get-the-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which document class you use. However from the pieces of code you shown, I didn't see how it will create a list of equations. Here is an example how to achieve it in `report` class.

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand{\listequationname}{List of Equations}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listofequations}{%
    \chapter*{\listequationname}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{\listequationname}}{\listequationname}}
    \@starttoc{loe}
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\labeleqn}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{loe}{section}{Equation \theequation\quad#1}%
}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listofequations
\clearpage
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Foo}
\begin{equation}\labeleqn{AGC}
AGC = Q_{fr} * \alpha_ {f}\label{Equation 1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\labeleqn{Mass–energy equivalence}
    E=M\cdot c^2\label{Equation 2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]