Failing to Add Equations in Table of Content
Good morning. I have used a template from overleaf for my Report, I have tried to remove the content I don't need and I want to add a list of Equations in the Table of contents. when I compile the project it is not listing the equations on the table of contents,
my project is starting with a blank page.
Would you please assist to fix this, I have attached the Thesis.cls file I was changing
\renewcommand\listofequations{
\btypeout{List of Equations}
\addtotoc{List of Equations}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listequationname
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listequationname}
              {\MakeUppercase\listequationname}}
    \@starttoc{loe}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}

\tableofcontents  


\lhead{\emph{List of Figures}}  
\listoffigures 


\lhead{\emph{List of Tables}} 
\listoftables  


\lhead{\emph{List of Equations}}  
\listofequations    


\begin{equation}\label{eq:VoltdropFormula}
   u=b\left(\rho_1\frac{L}{S}cos\varphi+\lambda L sin\varphi\right)l_B \citep{IEC60364-5-52:2009} 
\end{equation}


Welcome to TeX.SE. A quick tip: To pretty-print a LaTeX code block, open the editor window, highlight the code with your mouse, and click on the "{}" button in the ribbon above the editor window.

You appear to have attached a file that's employed by your document via the statement \documentclass[<various options>]{Thesis}. However, you have so far not provided any other code that's related to your document. In particular, we have no information yet regarding how you create the table of contents -- or why equations should be listed in the table of contents. Please edit your posting to provide a [minimal working example[(https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that generates the issue you want to fix.

here is the thesis.tex code

\tableofcontents
\lhead{\emph{List of Figures}}
\listoffigures
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\lhead{\emph{List of Tables}}
\listoftables
\lhead{\emph{List of Equations}}
\listofequations

No. Please edit your main posting, so that your code can be pretty-printed. Please don't abuse the comment section to post more than an absolutely mininimal code snippet. Also, your code snippet doesn't contain any equations, does it? So why should \listofequations generate a (non-empty) list of equations?

one of the eqs \begin{equation}\label{eq:VoltdropFormula}
u=b\left(\rho_1\frac{L}{S}cos\varphi+\lambda L sin\varphi\right)l_B \citep{IEC60364-5-52:2009}
\end{equation}

please edit your question to provide a minimal document we can compile to reproduce the output you want help with. you should also remove all the content from the class file which you can remove while still reproducing the problem. for example, we probably don't need t o see the settings for the title page or packages which load graphics. please read the link @Mico posted if you aren't sure how to do this.

Did you take the time to read the posting on the benefits of creating a minimal working example, which others can compile in order to replicate and thereby diagnose the issue you wish to fix?

you have shown no relevant code but what would you expect a list of equations to show???  unlike figures they don't have captions so there really isn't anything useful that can be put in such a list.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583419/adding-list-of-equations-into-an-existing-latex-style-sty-file/583426#583426
